# Detect closed client UDP channel in Netty 4

Tags: java, udp, netty

I'm using Netty as part of a UDP server which opens a number of persistent connections with various clients on a single server channel. I need to perform some cleanup when a client terminates the connection. Specifically, I need to know when the connection is terminated and from which IP address the terminating client is located at so that I can cleanup the data.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the Netty model, but I'm unsure how to detect this. I normally distinguish between various clients by checking the sender's IP address from the `DatagramPacket` instances, perhaps that is wrong and I should be using multiple channels or something like that? Either way, I'm looking for some way to handle a closed connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding UDP, not Netty. There is no such thing as a "persistent connection" in UDP, although there can be application-managed sessions, and UDP provides no information about whether the other endpoint is still active. Ideally, you'll have a "close" message, but you'll need to have a timeout or other mechanism to identify dead connections and clean them up (for crashed clients, etc.).  This will require some sort of garbage-collection process, maybe a background thread that checks a "last heard from" timestamp and closes inactive sessions.

Comment: I was beginning to suspect this, thanks, it makes sense now that you point it out. Would it be advisable to simply ping an unresponsive client and kill it if it takes too long to respond?

Comment: @JakeKing It's better to require the client to send keepalives.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, though could you briefly explain why that's better? Since the client will likely have a lot of traffic anyway, poking the quiet ones seems like it would be more effective.

Comment: @JakeKing A client doesn't have to send keepalives if it's actively sending data, but there are a few reasons, all efficiency/scalability, to put the burden on it. Basically, both ends know that the server needs updates, so the "client ping" just adds complexity on the server end and extra traffic. If the client is going to respond to a ping, it would have sent the keepalive (or another message) anyway, and now you just have a 1-second timer thread on each client instead of lots of extra bookkeeping on the server.

Comment: In fact you need to stop thinking about *clients* completely in UDP. There is one request and one response. That client doesn't have any context beyond the request/response. You may never hear from him again.

Comment: @EJP It sometimes does make sense to think of sessions in UDP, such as for games or VOIP. It really depends on the particular application.